# Python NoneTypeDataType while posting data to Flask with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to figure out how to make ajax data post to my flask controller,

- Without ajax, it works just find :

This is the form in my html template :

```
<form  method=post action="{{ url_for( 'editreals', id=realist.index(row), name='head') }}">
```

In my view.py, get the index 'id' and cast it :

```
i = int(request.args.get("id")
```

- With ajax, I'm using a jquery plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to edit in place :

  ```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".rubric").editable('{{ url_for('editskills') }}',{
        submit: 'Ok',
        cancel: 'Cancel',
        tooltip : 'Clic to edit',
        type : 'textarea',
        name : 'rubric'
     });
  });
  </script>

  <h3 class="rubric", id={{ sklist.index(row) }}>{{ row["rubric"] }}</h3>
  ```

In return I get a 500 error
I don't understand why the controller always send back that error :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneTypeDataType :
```

From the web debugger the data I sends seems ok to me :

```
FormData :
  rubric: datasubmitted
  id: 0
```

Those field are just Strings, nop ? Why python says they are NoneTypeDataType ?

[EDIT-1]

Headers :

```
Request URL:http://<Server-IPAddress>:5000/editskills
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:25
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:session=eyJsb2dnZWRfaW4iOnRydWV9.BcMSfg.j5SaVklwzSzTdttCciYL_9dqZNg
DNT:1
Host:<Server-IPAddress>:5000
Origin:http://<Server-IPAddress>:5000
Referer:http://<Server-IPAddress>:5000/competences
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)           Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
rubric:1Réseaux
id:0
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 23 Jan 2014 20:52:19 GMT
Server:Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.3
X-XSS-Protection:0
```

Preview :

```
File "/home/noa/virtualenv/folio/foliodev/portfolio/views.py", line 39, in editskills
v = liste[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

Sorry I made a mistake, there is the code which cause the error:

```
i = request.args.get("id", type=int)
v = liste[i]
```

If I try this instead :

```
i = int(request.args.get("id"))
```

It breaks directly to the cast :

```
i = int(request.args.get("id"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Which make me focus on why does the data I send are 'NoneType'

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: In the working code you are using `ind` (which is what you are looking for in your view), but the data you are sending via ajax is sending `id` ... shouldn't it be `ind`?

Comment: Yes it is, I edited the view to request the id and not ind, sry I forgot to specify it in my question.

Comment: Can you provide the *full* stack trace?

Comment: Hello, do you need more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your working `form` example you are sending the `id` in the query string (which makes it available to `request.args`).  jEditable is sending the `id` in the response *body* as part of the `POST` - Flask exposes this data under `request.form`.  Change `i = int(request.args.get("id"))` to `i = int(request.form.get("id"))` and things will work.

Comment: It work, thank you very much, I wasn't clear about this 2 ways to post data.